# Should I create a style in css or just add style to the element. What's the better practise?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so let's say I am coding HTML/CSS template and I see that I need to create a text with certain color and text-shadow. Should I create a different style in css file or just add style to the element? This `<span style="color: #f2f12; text-shadow: 0 2px 0 #f1f1f1">Text</span>` or this `<span class="styleforthistext">Text</span>` is better practise? If I know that I will use this color only for this text (only once).

Comment: If you've already got the style sheet, then I'd add the class attribute and pop the styles into the style sheet.

Comment: @bye consider marking one of the answers as accepted, in case you're satisfied with it. Otherwise, ask more questions about whatever is not clear to you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your html layout should only contain data. All styling should be done in separate css files.
This is a good practice for many reasons.

- First of all, your code becomes more clean and readable.
- Also, you could easily substitute your styles with another ones, not even touching the html.
- You could reuse your classes in multiple places (given that you name and structure them properly).
- If you name classes basing on semantics, your code becomes even more readable and easier to maintain.
- etc., etc.

Comment: SEO claim is apocryphal at best.

Comment: @steveax I'm not a SEO expert, but that's what I've heard. E.g.: http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-checking-your-page-size/6922/. Do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Page load time involves more than the size of the HTML and that article kinda proves my point - no evidence offered.

Comment: @steveax ok, removed that line from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself this, **what is the meaning carried by the differently styled text?**

Is it an *emphasized text*? Maybe a **strong text**? Is it a `<h3>title</h3>`?

Based on that, create the appropriate element, and style that on your stylesheet. Very few cases justify the use of the `style=` attribute, this isn't one of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate style in the CSS file is usually the better practice. It's the principle of separating your concerns - content is in the HTML, presentation (style) is in CSS (i.e. not inlined with the HTML) and behavior is in JavaScript (again, not inlined in the HTML).

Comment: what @user1394965 means is that CSS isn't a practice here, it's a neccessity. The question really is where to put the CSS - inline or in a separate file.